# Making an algorithm, but my IQ is too low

Tags: algorithm, math

OK, I have been trying to get my head around this for a while, but I think Im too tired to wrap my head around this.

Every week my script goes through a table and changes status of 60 new products from deactivated to activated. I want to make sure these 60 products are not all from 1 category, but rather from all categories that have products that can be activated.

Example products table

```
| productid | category     | status      |
| 1         | iPad 2       | deactivated |
| 2         | iPod Touch 4 | deactivated |
```

Example array, you are seeing category names, and number of products that can be activated.

```
array(9) {
  ["iPad 2"] => int(2)
  ["iPod Touch 5"] => int(2)
  ["iPod Touch 4"] => int(6)
  ["iPhone 3G/3GS"] => int(94)
  ["iPad 1"] => int(104)
  ["iPad Mini"] => int(150)
  ["iPhone 4/4S"] => int(174)
  ["iPhone 5"] => int(205)
  ["iPad 3/4"] => int(236)
}
```

Now, how would I go about activating products from all of these categories, divided nicely?

The resulting array I can compute roughly manually. That would be, category name, and products that will be activated. A total of 60 products, divided nicely across the categories.

```
array(9) {
  ["iPad 2"] => int(2)
  ["iPod Touch 5"] => int(2)
  ["iPod Touch 4"] => int(6)
  ["iPhone 3G/3GS"] => int(8)
  ["iPad 1"] => int(8)
  ["iPad Mini"] => int(8)
  ["iPhone 4/4S"] => int(8)
  ["iPhone 5"] => int(9)
  ["iPad 3/4"] => int(9)
}
```

But I lack the ability to program such an algorithm.
I'm hoping someone here is a bit brighter than me today?

Comment: Do you want the selections to be random or proportional to the number of items in each category?

Comment: [try this](http://www.energyfiend.com/meth-coffee-super-caffeinated-coffee)

Comment: thanks fredrik. iamnotmaynard, proportional to the number of items would be good, but random is also ok if thats easier to manage..

Comment: So you go 1) calculate proportions 2) normalize them 3) calculate number of elements for each category according to normalized proportion (i.e., according to probability) and 4) choose that number of products to be activated for each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
EvenlySelect(item_list):
  sorted_items = SortLowestToHighestCount(item_list)
  remaining_num_items = CountTotalNumberOfItems(item_list)
  return_list = Empty()
  while (!Empty(sorted_items)):
    desired_quantity = remaining_num_items / Size(sorted_items))
    if desired_quantity == 0:
      break
    quantity_to_add = 0
    if desired_quantity > sorted_items[0].quantity:
      quantity_to_add = sorted_items[0].quantity
    else:
      quantity_to_add = desired_quantity
    Append(Item(sorted_items[0].category, quantity_to_add), return_list)
    remaining_num_items -= quantity_to_add
    RemoveFirstElement(sorted_items)

  return return_list
```

The idea is: go from category with the smallest quantity to the one with the largest. At each step, figure out how many items you'd need from that category to be even (given what you've already chosen in previous steps). If the category has enough items, take that many. Otherwise take as many as you can.

Comment: yes it was something like this i ended up with :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Selection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //input arrays
        String[] categories = {"iPad 2","iPod Touch 5","iPod Touch 4","iPhone 3G/3GS","iPad 1","iPad Mini","iPhone 4/4S","iPhone 5","iPad 3/4"};
        int[] quantities = {2,2,6,94,104,150,174,205,236};
        //ensure that there's at least one item for each category
        int[] distributions = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        int[] intervals = new int[9];
        intervals[0] = 2;
        for (int i=1;i<9;i++) {
            intervals[i] = intervals[i-1]+quantities[i];
        }
        Random generator = new Random();
        int range = intervals[intervals.length-1];
        for (int j=0;j<51;j++) { //to fill the remaining 51 slots according roughly to their proportions
            int randomInt = generator.nextInt(range); //generate an integer between 0 and 2+2+6+94+104+150+174+205+236 at random
            if (randomInt < intervals[0]) {
                distributions[0]++;
            } 
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[0] && randomInt < intervals[1]) {
                distributions[1]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[1] && randomInt < intervals[2]) {
                distributions[2]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[2] && randomInt < intervals[3]) {
                distributions[3]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[3] && randomInt < intervals[4]) {
                distributions[4]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[4] && randomInt < intervals[5]) {
                distributions[5]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[5] && randomInt < intervals[6]) {
                distributions[6]++;
            }
            else if (randomInt >= intervals[6] && randomInt < intervals[7]) {
                distributions[7]++;
            }
            else {
                distributions[8]++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("array(9) {");
        for (int k=0; k< 9; k++) {
            System.out.println("  [\""+categories[k]+"\"] => int("+distributions[k]+")");
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
}
```

I've tested the complete and working code above and hope that the code is self-explanatory.

Here's a sample output that I just got:

```
array(9) {
  ["iPad 2"] => int(1)
  ["iPod Touch 5"] => int(1)
  ["iPod Touch 4"] => int(2)
  ["iPhone 3G/3GS"] => int(6)
  ["iPad 1"] => int(7)
  ["iPad Mini"] => int(11)
  ["iPhone 4/4S"] => int(8)
  ["iPhone 5"] => int(13)
  ["iPad 3/4"] => int(11)
}
```

The idea is simple: we first reserve one item for each category, which takes 9 slots away. Consider the remaining 51 slots one by one, each of which has an chance based on its proportion to go to its respective category. Since the total quantity of items is not large enough and we use the random function to generate an integer, we can't guarantee that the outcome completely conform to the proportion of each category. Nonetheless, I think the solution is good enough for your purpose.